# How can I parse IP addresses and address ranges with Perl?

Tags: perl, ip-address

I have list of IPs:

238.51.208.96/28
238.51.209.180-199
238.51.209.100-109
238.51.213.2-254
...

How can I easily parse them? I need first and last IP from range.
For the first line I can use Net::Netmask CPAN module, but what can I do with others lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::IP) module

If second patterns does not support, you may need to some changes to ips in advances like

```
238.51.209.180-199
```

to

```
238.51.209.180 - 238.51.209.199
```

by using some regex, for example,

```
$range =~ s/^((?:\d+\.){3})(\d+)-(\d+)$/$1$2 - $1$3/gm;
```

Full script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::IP;
my $range = "238.51.209.180-199";
$range =~ s/^((?:\d+\.){3})(\d+)-(\d+)$/$1$2 - $1$3/;
my $ip = new Net::IP ($range) || die;
print $ip->ip (), "\n";
print $ip->last_ip (), "\n";
```

Comment: `my $ip = new Net::IP ("238.51.209.180-199") || die;` output is `Died at ./andrey-zentavr.pl line 5.`

Comment: Thank you. I have added /gm too, I think its need multiline flag

Comment: I do not want my script to die.
If Net::IP($range) fails, I need to remake string to clear format.

Comment: Just change the script then. It's only an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can match IP addresses using the [Regexp::Common::net](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::net) package, and manipulate them (and get netmasks etc) with any number of modules on CPAN, including [Network::IPv4Addr](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Network::IPv4Addr), [NetAddr::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?NetAddr::IP) and [Net::CIDR](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::CIDR).

Comment: I desided to use smt like this:
# Check, what range format do we have?
 if($ipline =~ /^((?:\d+\.){3})(\d+)-(\d+)$/){
  $ipline =~ s/^((?:\d+\.){3})(\d+)-(\d+)$/$1$2 - $1$3/;
 }